# Why is Makerfab SIM808 ATMEGA328 Serial Port not showing up on Arduino IDE on my apple macbook pro?

Tags: macos, arduino, serial-port, atmega

Bought a [Makerfab SIM808 ATMEGA328 module from Robotshop](https://www.robotshop.com/ca/en/sim808-gps-module.html?gclid=CjwKCAjwiurXBRAnEiwAk2GFZuxg5hvwKlprw3_mZ6TUVe5CUmiP-Km5bFLZXUVqq35Eq0nuY0mayBoCK_8QAvD_BwE#Useful-Links) and I connect the micro usb to the module. The port does not show up on the ports list on the Arduino IDE and the documentation is very poor. Does anyone have any experience with this and know what I am missing.

Hardware details can be found [here](https://hackaday.io/project/28736-iot-sim808-gps-tracker-based-on-arduino).

This is the [datasheet](https://www.robotshop.com/media/files/pdf/sim808-gps-module-datasheet.pdf).

Any help would be appreciated here.

Comment: Possible cross site duplicate of [My Arduino isn't showing up on my computer. What should I do?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/46116)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you install the CP2104 driver to your PC before use it? This board use the CP2104 at the USB to TTL. Here is the driver:https://www.silabs.com/products/development-tools/software/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers
Please try it. Hope it help for you.

Comment: This got me somewhere but then the port */dev/tty.SLAB_USBtoUART*  does not show up as an option on the Arduino IDE port dropdown. I decided to use platformio but am not sure if it working. I am trying a few more options, any suggestion to move forward from this could help. 

macOS Sierra 10.12.6